# LARAVEL Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'patientiam.t_investigadors' doesn't exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo mi modelo creado como:

```
class t_investigador extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['t_investigador'];
}
```

y mi metodo de insercion es

```
 public function store(Request $request){

        // $request = count(array($request));

        $investigador = new t_investigador(array(
            'inv_nombre'     => trim($request->inv_nombre),
            'inv_apellPater' => trim($request->inv_apellPater),
            'inv_apellMater' => trim($request->inv_apellMater),
            'inv_cedula'     => trim($request->inv_cedula),
            'inv_correo'     => trim($request->inv_correo),
            'inv_telefono'   => trim($request->inv_telefono),
            'fk_ciu_codigo'  => trim($request->fk_ciu_codigo),
            'fk_ent_codigo'  => trim($request->fk_ent_codigo)
        ));

        $investigador->save();    
        $mensaje = "Se agrego el investigador";    
        $respuesta = response::json([
            'messaje' => $mensaje,
            'data' => $investigador
        ],201);

         return $respuesta; 

    }
```

los datos que envian desde el formulario lo tengo en Angular,

public form = {
    inv_nombre : null,
    inv_apellPater : null,
    inv_apellMater: null,
    inv_cedula: null,
    inv_correo: null,
    inv_telefono: null,
    fk_ciu_codigo: null,
    fk_ent_codigo: null
  }

Obvio los datos no llegan nulos se llenan despues que ingresan los valores por teclado, pero me esta generando un error en la insercion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo por qeu me buscar investigadors si lo tengo sin S aclaro que la tabla ya existia es decir no fue migrada desde laravel. Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: tienes los campos `updated_at` y `created_at` ? en la tabla?, laravel por defecto intenta insertar estos datos

Answer (score 0):

Laravel intentará por defecto buscar la tabla en la cual almacenará, en plural; es decir **investigadors**.

Si tu tabla no sigue esa convención, pues su nombre es en singular, entonces en el modelo asociado a la misma deberás declarar su nombre a través de una propiedad de este modo:

```
protected $table = 'investigador';
```

Aquí más información [table property](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#defining-models)

Por otro lado tu modelo en su nombre debería seguir la convención de nombres:

- Nombre en singular
- Primer letra mayúscula

Quedando como **Investigador**

Además de lo anterior, Eloquent espera las columnas created_at y updated_at, pero si las mismas no existen en tu tabla, entonces deshabilitarlas desde tu modelo con esta propiedad:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```